# Format parameter date oracle

Tags: oracle

i am trying to format a date which i will get via variable.

```
select  to_char(
          $$exec_Date          ,'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
         date
          from dual ;
```

resolved vale is

```
select  to_char(
          04-02-2015 17:19:52          ,'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
         date
          from dual ;
```

it work fine

```
select  to_char(
          sysdate          ,'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
         date
          from dual ;
```

Can some one help me what i am doing wrong here ? i have looked into

Comment: Looks like a string, not a date. Where is this code embedded - what language particularly, but also what is the data type? If it is a string then what conversion are you trying to do - you seem to just be dropping the century number, going from a 4-digit to 2-digit year?

Comment: variable is given by DI tool but in datetime data type .

Comment: So where are you seeing the 'resolved value', which already appears to have been formatted as a string? Editing your question to provide some context would probably be helpful.

Comment: Use TO_CHAR when you want to display the datetime in your desired format. For all sort of calculations, let the date be as it is. No need to convert it to string. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 04-02-2015 17:19:52

Oracle has no clue whether that value is a **DATE** or a **string** or what? You must first convert the literal to DATE using **TO_DATE**.

But, in your case, you are passing the value without **single quotes**, which means it is not a literal. So, you need to do this:

```
select  to_char(
          to_date('04-02-2015 17:19:52','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')          ,'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
         date
          from dual ;
```

Pay attention the single quotes and the to_date function.

You use **TO_DATE** to convert a literal into a DATE, **TO_CHAR** to convert a date into a literal. The **FORMAT MODEL** is what is desired mostly.

For all sort of calculations, let the date be as it is. No need to convert it to string. However, if you got a string, you need to first convert it to date for DATE calculations. Use **TO_CHAR** when you want to display the datetime in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do with that date?

If you're just using it for display purposes, then you don't need to do anything, as it's already a string (unless perhaps you need to change the format of the displayed date?).

If you need to convert it to a date, so you can store it in a DATE column, or use it for DATE comparisons, you would need to use `TO_DATE`, rather than `TO_CHAR`.

In short:

- if you're passing in a string (which is what you're doing) and you want to convert it into a DATE in Oracle, use `TO_DATE`
- if you want to display something that's a DATE datatype in a particular format, use `TO_CHAR`.

Hence, your `to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss')` works - it turns sysdate (which is of DATE datatype) into a string in that format.

In your example, you would need to do `to_date($$exec_Date, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`.

If you're then needing to reformat that to display it with a 2 digit year (seriously? I know y2k was 15 years ago, but still...!), you would then need to put a `to_char()` around it with the relevant format.